# Eclipse SWT browser with XULRunner 10 crashes on Javascript window.print

Tags: java, printing, crash, swt, xulrunner

I am try to use Eclipse SWT browser with XULRunner 10. But sometimes the
browser crashes while invoking Javascript window.print.
Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it may be Eclipse bug [372654](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372654).

This is marked as fixed in Eclipse 3.8 / 4.3 (Kepler)

Comment: Can I get the new/fixed eclipse swt jar?

Comment: You can download the current SWT jars from the Eclipse 4.3.1 [download page](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3.1-201309111000/)

Comment: hello i downloaded swt 4.3.1 from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3.1-201309111000/download.php?dropFile=swt-4.3.1-win32-win32-x86.zip
but the problem exists

Comment: I have enalbled silent printing without dialog

Comment: printing large contents makes the problem

Comment: @greg_449 Can you fix this or suggest any alternate solution?

Comment: I don't know anything about this other than what is stated in the bug report.

Comment: @greg_449 Any alternate solution to print?